# OLAP Tools - Excel - Calculated Measure - simple 'sum' function

Tags: excel, pivot, mdx, olap

I have a very simple question.

I am unfortunately a complete newbie in the field of MDX. I would like to check if a condition is met using a calculated measure. For this I use the following MDX statement via OLAP tools in Excel:

IIF([Measures].[Target]>0,1,NULL)

[image]

Thereby I get a correct display on row level, but not in the total result. There I expect a 17 instead of the 1. Surely the Sum function is missing there, but I have no idea how to apply it.

I would be very happy about any help. Thanks and greetings.

Comment: I think the better description is: I need a COUNTIF function.

Comment: I have a solution in the approach, however, I still need a different representation at row level than in the overall result. The following statement counts the rows that meet the condition:

COUNT(FILTER([Dimension].Members, [Measures].[Target]>0))

For the overall result it is the desired result, but not for the result on row level.

Comment: I found a way to distinguish between the row level and the overall result:

Case When [Dimension].CurrentMember.Level.Ordinal = 0 Then [Measure1] Else [Measure2] End

So I can use both statements contextually.

I'm pretty sure there is a more elegant solution for this, but for my requirement so far this solution is sufficient (for now).